# Combining (merging) neighbour points to one centred point in PostGIS (reducing density)?

Tags: postgis, mapbox-gl-js, combine

I'm new to spatial algorithms and PostGIS functionality. Currently I have a Pg 10 + Postgis 2.4 database with table of more than 400 000 records (points with additional properties), with Node.JS tile server that generates and serves tiles for Mapbox GL JS plugin using PostGIS `ST_ASMvt` function.  An d everything seems ok (generates very fast, caching without problems, etc), but there is one problem.

The problem is very big tiles (more than 2 mb) with big amount of features, so Mapbox GL JS renders it veeery sloooowly and eat a lot of memory (sometime my app is chrashing even on my laptop with 16 gb RAM). **I can't** just reduce the number of features by SQL `LIMIT` (just believe me, there are some business problems with the data in this case and on the map it looks very ugly).

[image: map examples, each tile contains N thsnd number of features]

And I think that I need to cluster some points that have a big density. So I want to merge the neighbors (and show as one point) at a high zooms and I think it will help with the memory and rendering speed (because of lesser number of features and tile size). But I don't know and cant find how to do this.

Comment: What version of PostGIS do you have?

Comment: Have you tried the ST_ClusterDBSCAN function ? http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_ClusterDBSCAN.html

Comment: Did you resolve this issue w/ ST_ClusterDBSCAN?

Answer (score 0):

One quick way that doesn't actually cluster the points (but with as many points as you have, no one may notice), is to use Mapbox's LabelGrid function to de-densify the points that are being returned:

https://github.com/mapbox/postgis-vt-util#labelgrid